# How to communicate with mobile devices using Bluetooth in j2me?

Tags: java-me, mobile, bluetooth

I  need to develop a project based on Bluetooth in mobile. Since I am new to j2me I studied some of the articles and run the project until the discovery of devices and services. I need to communicate between devices and transfer the desired files. I search code for client server communication through Bluetooth and got it but I didn't know how to run those code and implement further.

I have go through articles and I can run client server communication. Now I need to transfer the file and communicate to the user which was beyond the limit of my mobile through the another mobile which was within my limit.

Answer (score 0):

[JSR82.com](http://www.jsr82.com/) has many articles and tutorials about how to use bluetooth from J2ME.

Answer (score 0):

Better you refer the book, "BLUETOTH APPLICATION PROGRAMMING WITH JAVA API" by C.Balakumar. It is helpfull to you.